# Tkinter How to print results from functions in labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I am rather new to GUI's and Tkinter but what I am basically trying to do is have a platform whereby with a click of a button I can obtain share prices and related share info using the request and BS4 modules. I am using Python 2.7.

When I click the button on my GUI, the share price shows up perfectly on my label. However, it shows unusual info in the label below it where instead it should show the % and currency daily move. The reason for this is that I have linked the GUI python file to the other python file that I am using to "download" the prices and I have included the up or down price movements in a function.

So when I call the results of this function to be printed in the label - they are printed but with something along the lines of "function share_movement at 0x022B34F0"

Below is my GUI code and then the code for my other python file:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Share_price_info as kio_file

#Creating the parent window
root = tk.Tk()
f = tk.Frame(root)

#Title for window
root.title("My first GUI")

#Size of the window - min and max
root.maxsize(850, 850)
root.minsize(250, 250)

#Setting a fixed size of window on opening
root.geometry("800x750")

#Setting the background colour
root.configure(background="white")

title = tk.Label(root, text="Platform", fg="black", font="Helvetica 20 bold", bg="grey")
title.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

#Logo for top
topimg = tk.PhotoImage(file="stock_market.gif")
stock_img = tk.Label(root, image=topimg, bg="black")
stock_img.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)

#Entry to type which share you want to find info for
search = tk.Entry(root)
search.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W")

#Function to print out what has been searched for in the Entry bar
def search_bar():
    print search.get()
    kio_file.share_price()
    #if search.get() == "kio":
        #use the information from the share info script
        #kio_file.share_price()

#Search button
tk.Button(root, text="Search", command=search_bar) .grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="W")

#Button when pressed closes program.
exit_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Exit Platform", bg="black", fg="white", width=20, height=2, command=root.destroy)
exit_btn.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="E")   


#Label that prints the share info when the "KIO info" button is clicked
currentPrice = tk.StringVar(root, "Click for share info")
currentMovement = tk.StringVar(root, "Click for share info")

def setValues():
    price = kio_file.kio_price
    print price
    currentPrice.set(price)
    movement = kio_file.share_movement
    print movement
    currentMovement.set(movement)

#When button is clicked, the function as part of the "command" widget in the button code will run and the "textvariable" here
#which is linked to it will also be activated.
kio_printout = tk.Label(root, textvariable=currentPrice, bg='black', fg="white", width=40, height=3)
kio_printout.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

kio_printout = tk.Label(root, textvariable=currentMovement, bg='black', fg="white", width=40, height=3)
kio_printout.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

#When push the button the share details print out
kio = tk.Button(root, text="KIO info", bg="black", fg="white", width=30, height=2, command=setValues)
kio.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)


print root.grid_size()

#Run the program
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried to delete all unnecessary comments in my codes except for those that might be a little helpful.

## The other python file

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import matplotlib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup     #This parses the html text
import requests

#Get the current working directory
os.getcwd()
os.path.isfile("KIO.csv")

#Read the csv file with the share prices
df = pd.read_csv("KIO.csv")

#Average closing price for full year
average_close = closing.mean()
print average_close

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
#ping the website
r = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KIO.JO?p=KIO.JO", headers=headers)

#Opens the connection and downloads the webpage
kio_site = urllib2.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KIO.JO?p=KIO.JO")

#This will print all the html on the webpage
#kio_html = kio_site.read()

#Now closing the internet connection that you opened before
kio_site.close()

#now you want to parse the html file
page_soup = soup(r.text, "html.parser")

#print the html webpage to be properly nested:
#print page_soup.prettify()

#Specifically find certain elements
kio_price = page_soup.find("span", {"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"}).text

def share_movement():
    try:
        print page_soup.find("span", {"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataGreen)"}).text
    except:
        print page_soup.find("span", {"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)"}).text
```

The problem is basically with the "setValues" function in the first file and then the "share_movement" function in the second file since I do not think the Label knows which one to print. However, I needed to code it like this in order to consider the price going both up and down daily.

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Add `()` in the end of `movement = kio_file.share_movement`. You are not calling the function without the ending `()`, so you are printing the function object, instead of the function result.

Comment: It makes sense - however when I put in the () to call the function the label now print "None".

Comment: You should consider placing the code in your 'second' file in to a class with methods to return the share price/share movement  (or at least a function). I don't have beautiful soup but I can try to throw an example together.

Comment: Also not sure why you are using both requests and urllib2, generally only one is needed.

Comment: I am a bit unsure what you mean about creating a class? That will just make everything look more legible and easier to read - how will it resolve the unusual "None" that is printed within the Label when I click the button in the GUI? Regarding the urllib2 - ignore that - I initially tried to use that to get the online info and then used requests module. There was quite a bit of code and comments on my python file that I removed when posting the codes on this forum - I must have forgotten to remove that :-)

Comment: Just resolved the issue - petty mistake. Instead of "print page_soup.find("span", {"class": "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataGreen)"}).text" I was supposed to use "return". I cannot believe I missed that.

Comment: Nice you did. Contacts with `None` usually happen because we forget to return, or we forget that a function/method assigns a value to a var in place or just act with some side effect and we still assign it to some name.